# If number is a multiple of n - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this problem below. I can get it to print whether it's odd or even but I can't get it to print out the correct message if number is a multiple of 4.

Here is the problem: Ask the user for a number. Depending on whether the number is even or odd, print out an appropriate message to the user. If the number is a multiple of 4, print out a different message.

Here is my code:

```
number = input("Pick a number and I'll tell you if it's odd or even. ")

def odd_or_even():
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
        return("Your number is even.")
    elif int(number) % 4 == 0:
        return("Your number is a multiple of 4.")
    else:
        return("Your number is odd.")
print(odd_or_even())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a number is a multiple of 4, it is also an even number and that's why it always triggers your first condition and doesn't even check the second one. Change the order of the conditions, i.e.:

```
...
if int(number) % 4 == 0:
    return("Your number is a multiple of 4.")
elif int(number) % 2 == 0:
    return("Your number is even.")
...
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I thought the else if would still be checked even if the first condition was met.  Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @brimo No. In almost all languages `if` clause will short-circuit; i.e. terminate as early as it can.

Comment: @LarryLustig You are right, this is technically not short-circuiting but even without `return` it wouldn't have evaluated the `else` clause.